# how to drop publisher rtmp module?

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming

how to stop publisher in rtmp module , i use control module : http://localhost:6789/control/drop/publisher?app=live&name=91fde028680ea9a8195d4334e170db7e then it has drop publisher, then publisher connect again right back.

I want to stop completely, is there any way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop your publisher after kickoff from server-side, because it's because of the automatically retry of your publisher like OBS.

If you can't stop the publisher, you could use the callback to deny it for every retry.

1. Kickoff the publisher, by Nginx `drop/publisher`, or `kickoff` of SRS.
2. Stop the publisher if possible, such as OBS or FFmpeg.
3. Use callback to deny the publisher if can't stop it.

For callback, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70538194/17679565).